# Programmatically connect Sheets / request access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Is there a way for Google Script to request access to a Google Sheet using the Document Key? I've tried `openById()` and was hoping for it to trigger a request, but nope...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way which seems to work for me, but I will caveat it with the fact that it is not documented, so neither likely to be supported or recommended, and I imagine it could probably change at any time.

It requires making OAuth2 authenticated requests with the server, so there are a number of steps involved:

#### Ensure Drive is an enabled scope on your script

1. Under **File > Project Properties > Scopes**, check that the following scope is listed:

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
   ```
2. If it isn't listed then running a simple call like:

   ```
   DriveApp.createFile('', '');
   ```

   Should prompt you to allow access to Drive. Once done, you can remove this line from your script.
3. Verify that the required Drive scope is now listed.

#### Make a request for the file you wish access for

This sample function worked for me, but YMMV:

```
function requestShare(spreadsheetId) {
  var request = {
    requestType: 'requestAccess',
    itemIds: spreadsheetId,
    foreignService: 'explorer',
    shareService: 'explorer',
    authuser: 0
  };
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/sharing/commonshare';
  var params = {
    method: 'POST',
    payload: request,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Call the `requestShare` function with the ID of the spreadsheet you are wishing to request access to.

I tested this between two accounts, and received sharing request emails, which when clicked, showed the dialog with the correct requestor details in.

Hope this helps.