# Using App Scripts to Bulk Request Access to large amount of Google Drive files

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet where in column A are a list of hundreds of files (actual URL or the ID of the file)  - all of which are on a variety of people's drives and various folders.  I have access to none of them.  Instead of hovering over each URL, and clicking "request access", is there a way to use app script to "bulk" request access across every file URL (or file ID, whichever is easiest) to save time?

I'm ultimately making a copy of each of those files I get access to, and moving them to a new folder (which I was able to do with some old stack overflow threads using App Script).  This is to help "consolidate" core material into a single accessible folder for knowledge management.

I've tried searching stack overflow for a similar challenge, but haven't had any luck finding out of this is feasible.

Comment: You said `I have access to none of them.` So what is the point of the script?

Comment: The question is to request access to all of them in bulk - I'm wondering if that's feasible to do a 'automated access request' for each document in column A  vs. go to each file and click request access for each one.  

Once I have access to all of them, I have a seperate script to modify & migrate as needed.

Comment: I did some additional searching and found this, which seems to be similar request, but not sure how to modify it such that it looks at the entire range from A1:A to request access for all those files

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628974/programmatically-connect-sheets-request-access